# Is NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore certified to work without a connection?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults, icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

The documentation doesn't seem very clear about this, but can I rely on NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore to persist data locally when the device is not connected, or should I also use a NSUserDefaults?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [iCloud design doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH6-SW11) with regards to Key Value storage

*Always effectively available. If a device is not attached to an account, changes created on the device are pushed to iCloud as soon as the device is attached to the account.*

(in the table at the bottom of the page)